# I Want to use input while program is running in while loop

Tags: python, input, user-input

I want it so that my program will take input while running without disturbing the execution of program! If possible I would also like to take input while print statements are continuously running and it would be nice if program is small!

I tried running input in while loop of python but that did not work as the rest of the program wasn't executing until I gave the input

## using python programming language

Comment: Search something about `sys.stdin`. `sys` is a Python package. You can use `sys.stdin` to receive data from keyboard. So `stdin` become an input source for example for `select()` Python instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking of Async programming, I'am not quiet experienced with that using Python, but do research within that topic.